# Accessing form Array values to display Mat Error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

FormGroup

```
this.locationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          locationName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
          locationURL: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
          workTiming: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
              beginTime: new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
            })
          ])
        })
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div formArrayName="workTiming" >
         <div *ngFor="let item of workTiming.controls;                  
                      let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
            <div class="container">
            <mat-form-field class="responsive">
                <input type="time" required formControlName="beginTime" matInput placeholder="Begin Time">
                <mat-error *ngIf="workTiming.get('beginTime').hasError('required')"> Enter begin time </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need some help on how to access the formControl name of 'beginTime' inside mat-error, since i'm using the formArray, I'm not sure on how to access it. If I give like in the code I get the error as follows

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for trying, I found the solution with the following code:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="workTiming.controls[pointIndex].get('beginTime').hasError('required')"> Enter begin time </mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the nested form directly which is not available for outside context. Access the nested form through parent form same like you access JS object elements:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="locationForm.get('workTiming.beginTime').hasError('required')"> 
  Enter begin time 
</mat-error>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the above answer doesn't work as expected. It worked with the following code:
<mat-error *ngIf="workTiming.controls[pointIndex].get('beginTime').hasError('required')"> Enter begin time </mat-error>

Answer (score 0):

Can be writtern as

```
<mat-error *ngIf="item.get('beginTime').errors?.required"> Enter begin time </mat-error>
```